# Using font awesome icon as uploadlabel

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome

I am developing a website in Angular 2. I want to be able to upload images by clicking on a icon from font awesome, but i am having problems doing this. I can upload images when i use a label for this, but now when using font awesome icons i can't

What i have right now:

```css
 #pic {
 border-radius: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-size: 240px;
 border-style: none;
 border: 2px solid black;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

 #pencilicon {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 85px;
 margin-top: 85px;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
 }  

 #uploadinput{  
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: -1; 
 text-align: left;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="picture">
  <input type='file' (change)="readUrl($event)"id="uploadinput">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" for="uploadinput" id="pencilicon" aria-
   hidden="true">     </i>
  <img [src]="imageurl" id="pic" >
  </div>
```

Comment: did you try bootstrap, it has easy to do with this

Comment: No have not tried that

Comment: what happens,, do you get any errors in console? can you make a working example,, I don't see fontawesome icon?

Comment: I don't get any errors, I can see the icon in my program, but not in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the font awesome library into your page and give the appropriate icon like so:

`<i class="fa fa-upload"></i>`.

See the code snippet below for an example and demo of your requirement.

```css
input[type="file"].novisible {
    display: none;
}
input[type="file"].novisible + label {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 border-radius:50%;
 border:2px solid #999;
 display:inline-flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="file" class="novisible" id="file_upload">
<label for="file_upload" class="btn btn-md btn-teak"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> <span>Upload</span></label>
```

Comment: Simply saying `try this` is not a good approach. You should explain your answer for the OP and the community to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your icon in a label ?
Personnaly I do like that (with Ember.js)

```
<input type='file' (change)="readUrl($event)"id="uploadinput">
<label for="uploadinput">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" for="uploadinput" id="pencilicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>{{uploadLabel}}</span> 
  <!-- This is then switched to file name -->
</label>
```

CSS :

```
input[type="file"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999%;

  & + label {
    // your label style
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fits your method is attached to input wich have z-index -1, it's impossible to click it now.

Change z-index to 999 and click on the top border of the circle.

Your method should be run when you click on the circle, not input.

Comment: I can see that. Should i just move the (change)="readUrl($event)" down to the "i" tag?

Comment: try this <div id="picture">
  <input type='file' (change)="readUrl($event)"id="uploadinput" #file>
  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" for="uploadinput" id="pencilicon" aria-
   hidden="true" (click)="this.file.click()">     </i>
  <img [src]="imageurl" id="pic" >
  </div>

Comment: This works, thanks. what does the method in the click do?

Comment: when you click o <i>  they do click event on an element with #file. Simple and work :)